# How come ctx.resetTransform() doesn't work when a very specific thing happens? It gives no errors too

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, oop, html5-canvas

I am programming an OOP 2d canvas game, and I am seeing some weird behaviour with my code. When inside "e", the workspace, there is two or more of the same object but nothing else, `ctx.resetTransform` somehow does not work, but the moment I create a new object of a different type in console, ie. `e.create('bullet')`, the bug goes away. Does anyone know why that is?

```js
var c = document.querySelector("canvas");
ctx = c.getContext("2d", {alpha: false});

const objs = {
  flower: {
    name: "flower",
    rot: 45,
    vel: {x: 0, y: 0},
    pos: {x: 50, y: 100},
    size: {x: 100, y: 100},
    sprite: [
      [0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5, "green"],
      [0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4, "pink"],
    ],
  },
  bullet: {
    name: "bullet",
    rot: 0,
    vel: {x: 0, y: 0},
    pos: {x: 50, y: 100},
    size: {x: 5, y: 10},
    sprite: [[0, 0, 1, 1, "black"]],
  },
};

var e = [];

e.create = function (cr) {
  crr = structuredClone(objs[cr]);
  e[e.length] = crr;
  return crr;
};

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    var obj = e[i];

    for (ii = 0; ii < obj.sprite.length; ii++) {
      ctx.resetTransform();
      ctx.translate(
        obj.pos.x + obj.size.x,
        obj.pos.y + obj.size.y
      );
      ctx.rotate((obj.rot / 180) * Math.PI);
      ctx.translate(
        -(obj.pos.x + obj.size.x),
        -(obj.pos.y + obj.size.y)
      );
      ctx.fillStyle = obj.sprite[ii][4];
      ctx.fillRect(
        obj.pos.x +
          obj.sprite[ii][0] * obj.size.x -
          obj.size.x / 2,
        obj.pos.y +
          obj.sprite[ii][1] * obj.size.y -
          obj.size.y / 2,
        obj.sprite[ii][2] * obj.size.x,
        obj.sprite[ii][3] * obj.size.y
      );
    }
  }
}

setInterval(() => {
  render();
}, 50);

setInterval(() => {
  e[0].pos.x = Math.random() * c.width;
}, 50);

e.create("flower");
e.create("flower");
```

```html
<canvas height="1080" width="1920"></canvas>
```

Comment: I've unminified your code with [prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/). I suggest always doing this so your code is readable to other developers. Also, you've introduced global variables in your loops. Please use `var` or `let` for those. Thanks. Beyond that, I'm not really sure I understand your question. Can you clarify what the issue is? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Hi, @ggorlen, thanks for minifying my code. Try running the code in a new tab and run `e.create("bullet")` in devtools to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious but with the CanvasRenderingContext2D's `resetTransform()` method the point of time actually calling it is important. To cite the [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/resetTransform) :

> Whenever you're done drawing transformed shapes, you should call resetTransform() before rendering anything else.

So the remedy is pretty easy - move `ctx.resetTransform();` from the beginning to the end of your for-loop - otherwise it might result in the 'ghosting images' you've experienced.

```js
var c = document.querySelector("canvas");
ctx = c.getContext("2d", {alpha: false});

const objs = {
  flower: {
    name: "flower",
    rot: 45,
    vel: {x: 0, y: 0},
    pos: {x: 50, y: 100},
    size: {x: 100, y: 100},
    sprite: [
      [0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5, "green"],
      [0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4, "pink"],
    ],
  },
  bullet: {
    name: "bullet",
    rot: 0,
    vel: {x: 0, y: 0},
    pos: {x: 50, y: 100},
    size: {x: 5, y: 10},
    sprite: [[0, 0, 1, 1, "black"]],
  },
};

var e = [];

e.create = function (cr) {
  crr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objs[cr]));
  e.push(crr)
 
};

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    var obj = e[i];

    for (ii = 0; ii < obj.sprite.length; ii++) {
      ctx.translate(
        obj.pos.x + obj.size.x,
        obj.pos.y + obj.size.y
      );
      ctx.rotate((obj.rot / 180) * Math.PI);
      ctx.translate(
        -(obj.pos.x + obj.size.x),
        -(obj.pos.y + obj.size.y)
      );
      ctx.fillStyle = obj.sprite[ii][4];
      ctx.fillRect(
        obj.pos.x +
          obj.sprite[ii][0] * obj.size.x -
          obj.size.x / 2,
        obj.pos.y +
          obj.sprite[ii][1] * obj.size.y -
          obj.size.y / 2,
        obj.sprite[ii][2] * obj.size.x,
        obj.sprite[ii][3] * obj.size.y
      );
     
       ctx.resetTransform();
    }
  }
}



e.create("flower");
e.create("flower");

setInterval(() => {
   e[0].pos.x = Math.random() * c.width;
  render();
}, 590);
```

```html
<canvas height="300" width="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yes, so basically, the canvas context is a state machine, even in the next interval callback, it will maintain its state, and `clearRect()` is affected by the CTM. Now, that doesn't explain why adding a new object in the console was preventing the issue (hint: the object's x and y positions where resetting the translate to (0, 0))